# Android I don’t know if I can meet my needs ,I want to use adb root to achieve,User profile

Tags: android, adb

### Android  I don’t know if I can meet my needs

### I want to use adb root to achieve

One app realizes multi-user data

```cs
//User profile

adb shell am start com.tencent.mm/com.tencent.mm.ui.LauncherUI --here User profile 001
adb shell am start com.tencent.mm/com.tencent.mm.ui.LauncherUI --here User profile 002
adb shell am start com.tencent.mm/com.tencent.mm.ui.LauncherUI --here User profile 003
adb shell am start com.tencent.mm/com.tencent.mm.ui.LauncherUI --here User profile 004
adb shell am start com.tencent.mm/com.tencent.mm.ui.LauncherUI --here User profile 005
adb shell am start com.tencent.mm/com.tencent.mm.ui.LauncherUI --here User profile 006
```

Is this idea feasible?

I think every time I run the app, I use adb to specify which configuration file the app uses to run, so as to achieve data independence. Data isolation. Realize the effect of multi-user login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No answer
No answer
No answer
close